# Mapping a Spring Form

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I have a form where suppose is preselect the languages of the person that is presented. What should put on the path or is something else wrong?

This to classes are mapping by hibernate and I get a object Person with a Set of Language.

```
public class Person{
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String age;
    private Set<Language> languages;
    ...
    setters and getters
}

public class Language{
    private int personId;
    private String language;
    ...
    setters and getters
}
```

in the controller I insert a list of all availables languages(Strings) and this is how my JSP looks like

```
<form:form action="update.do" commandName="person" method="post" name="create-person">
    ...
    <form:select multiple="true" path="languages.language" items="${allLanguages}" />
    ...
</form:form>
```

I did it with Strings before, but I don't know how to manage it with the class Language

**EDIT**
I forgot to say that `allLanguages` is a list of `String`

Comment: this will work also to populate the Set when submit?

Comment: `commandName="person"` are you using simple form controller still ?

Comment: @sankrish yes, I'm editing just a part of a large old controller. the code above is just an example

Answer (score 0):

1) `languages` is a Set, therefore it does not have property `language`
2) You will need to get an element from your set to use it
3) Your select allows `multiple="true"` at the same time you only use one value to set it...

Comment: I wrote a "example" and ask because don't know. the values are populates by items="${allLanguages}

Comment: Specifying the `path="..." ` allows you to pre-select some of the values,  `items="..."` builds the list

Comment: @GermanArlington what I need is pre-select all `Set<Language>` content on the list of `allLanguages`

Comment: AFAIK You can't do that in one operation - you will have iterate over `items` and set `selected` for each selected element.

Answer (score 0):

From your comment ,

```
<form:form action="update.do" commandName="person" method="post" name="create-person">
    ...
    <form:select multiple="true" path="languages" items="${allLanguages}" />
    ...
</form:form>
```

assuming `${allLanguages}` has the list of strings.

**Note** :

**Path** is the name of your model class variable that is to be associated with the input field.

**items** is the list of values that you have sent from the controller

Comment: I think that the problem is that `languages` is a Language.class and `allLanguages` is a String.class

Comment: `allLanguages ` contains list of strings right . so you need to bind the selected variable with model class attribute . i guess making the `multiple` should allow you